# Get category name with these post by custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I want category name with these post name by custom post type. 
Example:

```
Category Name: Birds
Post Name: Peacock

Category Name: Cities
Post Name: Jaipur
```

Comment: Ok, then for `Peacock`, the category name is `Birds` and for `Jaipur` the category name is `Cities` . That is the best answer that you can get for the question you posted. For more detailed help , post what you have done. What exactly is the problem and Write a proper question, on which language (php,, Java, C , C++ etc) you are doing it. Dont just put php/wordpress on the tags.

Comment: And forgot to tell, Try the WP Help and support first. BTW have you seen this (assuming you are working on Wordpress) http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The answer is:
polling-cat is name of taxanomy name of custom post type.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'polling-cat' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->name;
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'polling-cat' => $term->slug,
            'post_type' => 'polling',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
            the_title();
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```